# singular homology negative of a singular simplex

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $n\geq 1$ and $X$ be a topological space and $\sigma\in C_n(X)$ be a cycle, where $C_n(X)$ is the singular $n$-chain group. Let $p:\Delta^n\rightarrow\Delta^n$ be a permutation of the coordinates, where $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-simplex. I want to show directly and rigorously that $[\sigma p]\in H_n(X)$ is the negative of $[\sigma]\in H_n(X)$ if $p$ is odd and equal if $p$ is even (i.e. if the permutation corresponding to $p$ is odd or even).

Comment: Why $[\sigma] \in H_n(X)$ is defined? You said that $\sigma$ is a simplex. $\sigma$ has to be a cycle ($\partial \sigma = 0$) to induce an element in homology group.

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention that $\sigma$ is a cycle. Never said that $\sigma$ is a singular simplex though. I hope the notation $\sigma p$ is ok.

Comment: I would try to use that your $c$ is just the image under a continuous map $\varphi:\Delta_n \to X$ of a nice cycle on $\Delta_n$ and there your permutation should be controlable. and then you should be able to push that result forward using that $H(\varphi)$ is a grouphomomorphism.
sorry, i am lazy and that might get a little fiddely.

Comment: Your question does not make too much sense because it is very difficult that a singular simplex $\sigma$ is a cycle. In fact we have $\partial \sigma = \sum_{i=0}^n d_i \sigma$, where $d_i \sigma(t_0,\ldots,t_{n-1}) = \sigma (t_0,\ldots,t_{i-1},0,t_i,\ldots,t_{n-1})$. This sum is $0$ iff we can split $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ into pairwise disjoint sets $\{i,j\}$, where $j \ne i$, $d_j \sigma =  d_i \sigma$ and $i + j$ is odd. If $n$ is even, this is never possible, and for $n$ odd it is a severe restriction.